# Inserting text before a character or on a new line using sed?

Tags: sed, latex

I am trying to use a script to insert \cbstart{} and \cbend{} tags in a latex file when new text occurs.

```
end=$(( $start + $diff ))
sed -i "" "${start}s/^/\\\\cbstart{} /" "$OUT"
sed -i "" "${end}s/$/ \\\\cbend{}/" "$OUT"
```

However, when a \cbend{} tag is placed on a new line that contains a comment at the end:

```
\cbstart{} Example text. %Example commment \cbend{}
```

Commenting out the end tag.  Is there a way to use sed to place the \cbend{} tag before a % or on a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
sed -i ""  "${end}s/\\( %.*\\|$\\)/ \\\\cbend{}\\1/" "$OUT"
```

With saner escaping

```
sed -i ""  "${end}"'s/\( %.*\|$\)/ \\cbend{}\1/' "$OUT"
```

---

I did test this before posting:

```
end=""
{ echo foo; echo "bar % with comment"; } | 
sed "${end}"'s/\( %.*\|$\)/ \\cbend{}\1/'
```

```
foo \cbend{}
bar \cbend{} % with comment
```

---

Since the OP is on a Mac, the sed incantation required is:

```
sed -i "" -E "${end}"'s/( %.*|$)/ \\cbend{}\1/' "$OUT"
```

Comment: Using either of those returns sed: 1: "sed": unterminated substitute pattern.  Removing the second sed removes the returns, but either way it doesn't add \cbend{} at all.

Comment: What version of sed are you using?

Comment: On a macbook, PROJECT:text_cmds-84

Comment: Try: `sed -i "" -E "${end}"'s/( %.*|$)/ \\cbend{}\1/' "$OUT"`